# Run NUXT without server

Tags: deployment, server, nuxt.js, generate

How can I run a static NUXT project without a server?

That's what I did:

1. I created a new project (without any line of code) with VUETIFY
2. I ran the command npn run generate
3. I went to dist/index.html
4. The project opens but no link is clicked
5. I added the line in nuxt.config.js

   route: {
   base: '/ProjectName/'
   },
6. I ran generate again
7. The links are still not clicked, And if there is a clicked link it points to drive c

Comment: I think you are asking, how you can host the project through some service like apache?

Comment: No. My goal is to put NUXT within webview.

Comment: webview, is a concept in android, right?

Comment: yes. is like browser.

Comment: Isn't it correct, that we need to have a URL to display the same in webview?

Comment: is correct. and I want via URL of file

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to hash mode in your router! (https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router/#mode)

In your nuxt.config.js it should look like this:

```
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  ssr: false, // Disable Server Side rendering

  router:
  {
    mode: 'hash', // switch from history mode, that requires a server to fake filesystem calls, to totally client based approach where all urls prefixed with #.
    base: './', // change to './' if you want to test it locally
  },
```

Now you should be able to use "npm run generate" and just open the index.html file in your "dist" directory.